# How do I use a vuejs plugin with Laravel Spark's build system?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-spark

I've been trying to get a datepicker plugin working in my Laravel Spark app with Vuejs.

I've tried adding to app.js:

```
var datepicker = require('vuejs-datepicker');
Vue.use(datepicker);
```

But I get

```
plugin.apply is not a function(…)
```

in the JS console.

I've also tried:

```
var datepicker = require('vuejs-datepicker').default;
Vue.use(datepicker);
```

which yields:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'installed' of undefined(…)
```

Am I being dumb? As I can't find any references to my errors in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I normally import this into a parent component .vue file e.g

```
<script>
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'

export default {
   components: {
      Datepicker
   }
}
</script>

<template>
   <datepicker></datepicker>
</template>
```